# In SAS, how to do a loop INSIDE a group using the following characteristics

Tags: loops, sas

I have the following problem:

```
data example;
input channel $ program $ item1 item2 GOAL1 GOAL2;
datalines;
CS A 100 10 100 10
CS A 101 9 100 9
CS B 102 11 102 11
CS B 101 14 101 11
BD A 200 210 200 210
BD A 201 209 200 209
BD B 202 211 202 211
BD B 201 214 201 214
;
run;
```

First, I need to notice that operations are going to be performed on channel-program level.
Second, a third variable call THIRD equals item1 in its first entry by group. However, in the second entry of third it will vary: if item1_entry1

```
data poli;
set poli;
by channel program;
array prog{*} A B; /*IN my original data I have 3 programs, so the solution has to be general*/
third=item1; /*So the first entry of item1 will be equal in third*/
do k=1 to dim(prog);
if program=prog{k} then do;
if lag(item1)<lag(item1) then THIRD=lag(item1)
else THIRD=item1;
end;
end;
run;
```

As expected the code does not give me what I want.
Specifically THIRD and FOURTH should be equal to the variables GOAL1 and GOAL 2.

NOTE: The idea behind the comparison is that always the higher levels are going to be greater or equal than the lower levels, and the lower levels cannot be greater than the upper levels: I can't have 100 and then 101, it should be 100 and 100 for one group.

Comment: Could you show what the results should look like based on your `example` data set? I have a hard time understanding what you're asking for. Until I do, I should point out that using `lag` functions conditionally (`if` statements) can be bad idea and may not do what you think it will (see [link](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings09/055-2009.pdf))

Comment: Thank you. It is on the dataset above where it says goal1 and goal2. It also says that at the end of my post. Right above the note.

Comment: poorly asked question.  show the actual data set you want to get.  also show both input data sets

Answer (score 0):

Your description is a bit unclear. I think you want to compute a new variable want1, which      is set to the value of item1 at the beginning of each by group. And within a by group, it decreases if item1 decreases, else stays the same. I would try (untested):

```
data want;
   set example;
   by channel program;
   retain want1;
   if first.program then want1=item1;
   else want1=min(want1,item1);
run;
```

Comment: I will try it tomorrow and report if it was successful. Thanks.